# If/Else Statement Not Evaluating

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a little helper function that is not evaluating on either the If or Else.

I know the function is being called because I have the `nlapiLogExecution`, which is how you debug in NetSuite. Notes on what is being logged are with the code.

How is this possible? I have tried to use `==` operator as well. I also tried to set it as a variable inside the function (which I don't think is necessary).

```
function convertUnit(unit, cubicMeters){
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','convertUnitFunction',typeof(unit))
    // typeof is String
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','convertUnitFunction',unit)
    // value is Each
    if (unit === 'Each'){
        return cubicMeters
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','equals Each', cubicMeters)
        // does not log here
    }
    else {
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','else statements', 'equals else')
        // Does not log here
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `if` condition is true your function returns *before* reaching the log function.

Comment: Place the 'return cubicMeters' as the last statement within the block

Comment: @nnnnnn yep your right doh.  I guess I have another issue somewhere downstream from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are entering the `if` statement, but the function `return`s before you can log anything. Try switching the order of the `return` and log statements:

```js
function convertUnit(unit, cubicMeters){
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','convertUnitFunction',typeof(unit))
    // typeof is String
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','convertUnitFunction',unit)
    // value is Each
    if (unit === 'Each'){
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','equals Each', cubicMeters)
        // will log something now if you pass 'Each'
        return cubicMeters
    }
    else {
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','else statements', 'equals else')
        // will log something if the else branch is taken
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning before it gets to the `nlapiLogExecution` in the `'Each'` section. Not sure why it isn't running on the else though, unless you are only passing `'Each'`